# Scala lambda with multiple =>

Tags: scala, lambda, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I am learning Scala and see the follow code in a tutorial

```
case class Email (
    subject: String,
    text: String,
    sender: String,
    recipient: String)

type EmailFilter = Email => Boolean
def newMailsForUser(mails: Seq[Email], f: EmailFilter) = mails.filter(f)

val notSentByAnyOf: Set[String] => EmailFilter = 
    senders => email => !senders.contains(email.sender)
```

I understand that notSentByAnyOf is a function type that has the signature type Set[String] => EmailFilter.

However, I am not sure what 
**senders => email => !senders.contains(email.sender)** means.

Can I please get some explanation?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in what the type `EmailFilter` is.

An `EmailFilter` is defined as:

```
type EmailFilter = Email => Boolean
```

Which means it's a function from `Email` to `Boolean`. Now let's look at `notSentByAnyOf`:

```
senders => ...
```

is a function that given senders returns something. We know from the signature that something needs to be an `EmailFilter`. Since we know `EmailFilter` is really a function `Email => Boolean`, then that is what should be on the right side of the arrow<sup>1</sup>:

```
senders => (email => !senders.contains(email.sender))
           |________________________________________|
                               |
                            EmailFilter
```

So, `notSentByAnyOf`, is a function that given a set of `String`, returns a function `Email => Boolean`.

<sub>[1] The extra parenthesis in the example are just for emphasis. As in the original code, they can be omitted.</sub>